# How do I stop my island from sliding across the floor?

Tags: wooden-furniture, laminate-floor

I've recently moved into a new apartment and bought an [Ikea Stenstorp](http://www.ikea.com/ca/en/catalog/products/30219832/) island for my kitchen, and it's been solid so far except for one key issue: it slides across my basic condo laminate flooring like it's on ice. It looks like there's some plastic nubs on the feet, but they don't do much to stop the island's movement.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this in a way that won't damage the floor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options...  You can remove the non-marring plastic feet provided by Ikea, and replace them with some rubber nail or screw on feet, or you can get rubber "caster cups" that the existing feet can set on.  Rubber will provide protection between the floor and the table, but will stop if from sliding.

You should be able to find both and any home improvement store.

Screw on rubber feet (found on Amazon):

[image: rubber feet]

Rubber caster cups (image from lowes.com)

[image]

Comment: If the rubber feet still don't keep it in place, another option is the sticky rubber pads sold to [keep cell phones in place](http://www.amazon.com/Sticky-Slide-Phone-Mount-Holder/dp/1395871035) on car dashboards. They might leave some residue on the floor when you move out but they'll hold the island in place - they are very sticky without being adhesive.

Comment: I think I would try [shelf grip liner](http://www.amazon.com/Con-Tact-Premium-Non-Adhesive-Non-Slip-12-Inches/dp/B001AH8PLI) before I would do the cell phone gripper, but it's an option I wouldn't have thought about!

Comment: I'll have to give the rubber feet a try, seems like a solid suggestion--hopefully the increased surface area will increase traction too.

Answer (score 0):

Small rubber pads under the feet. Not from the hard rubber-plastic end of the spectrum - somewhat soft rubber. "Furniture floor gripper" will bring up some results. Or you can cut up an old mouse pad.

Alternatively, if you want to be able to move it easily and then have it stay put, locking rubber tired casters (but that will also raise it up.)